# How to clear value from cell if value in another column is present?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have df that looks like this:

```
col1    col2 
NaN     text
text    text
NaN     text
NaN     text
```

I want to clear the value in `col2` if `NaN` if present in `col1`.

New df should look like this:

```
col1    col2 
NaN     
text    text
NaN     
NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a `mask`ing operation:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].mask(df.col1.isna(), '')
# df['col2'] = np.where(df.col1.isna(), '', df['col2'])

df
   col1  col2
0   NaN      
1  text  text
2   NaN      
3   NaN
```

If you want NaNs in the second column instead of blanks, omit the second parameter to `mask`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dropna` + `reindex`

```
df.dropna('col1').reindex(df.index) # fixing by cold :-)

   col1  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1  text  text
2   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Actually should be `df.dropna('col1').reindex(df.index)`; and make sure this still works when there are more than two columns.

Answer (score 0):

***1st Step:*** Create `df` by copying OP's sample.(copy OP's sample first and then run following command).

```
df=pd.read_clipboard();
```

***2nd Step:*** Could you please try following here.

```
df.loc[df['col1'].isnull(), 'col2'] = ''
df
```

Output will be as follows.

```
   col1  col2
0  NaN
1  text  text 
2  NaN
3  NaN
```